# Problema con app.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml, configuración

Tengo un problema para usar mi aplicación. En ella llamo a varios servicios Web los cuales descargan un arcchivo en formato CSV. El archivo pesa más de 15 Mb.

Cuando el archivo es chico puedo fácilmente descargarlo, pero cuando llego a los 15 Mb solo descarga los mismos 3 Mb máximo.

Se que esto está relacionado con el archivo de `app.config`, y aunque he tratado de varias formas no logro cambiarlo bien.

¿De qué forma podria realizar estos cambios?

Aquí está el código del arthivo `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="DashboardSoap" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000"
                 maxBufferSize="200000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="200000000">
                  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                       maxArrayLength="2000000"
                       maxStringContentLength="2000000"/>
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="DashboardSoap1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://localhost/testApp/Dashboard.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DashboardSoap"
                contract="WS.DashboardSoap" name="DashboardSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: No obtienes ningun mensaje de error ? la verdas es raro que descargue 3Mb pero no se genere ningun exception. WCF tiene un limite en el tamaño, pero veo que lo defines en el config al definir "maxReceivedMessageSize"

Comment: No tengo nungun mensaje de error. El solo me genera el archivo limitado a 3 mb.

Comment: @Aarancibia Hiciste todos los cambios sugeridos en el web.config del servicio o en el cliente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que se trata de un servicio `asmx` en ese caso para aumentar el tamaño de transferencia deberias cambiar la configuracion

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>
```

[How to: Enable a Web Service to Send and Receive Large Amounts of Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528822.aspx)

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta. Hice los cambios y no hay diferencia, tengo el mismo archivo de descarga

Comment: pero ampliaste los valores de maxRequestLength? no uses los que estan en el ejemplo

Comment: Si lo amplie bastante a 409600000 pero no hubo diferencia.

Comment: intentaste agregar un web referende en lugar de un service reference? http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/consuming-web-service-in-Asp-Net-web-application/Images/FAddsevice.png  si te fijas en la imagen al agregar el "Service Reference" puede cambiar la opcion y agregar una referencia mas simple.

Comment: La definicion del httpRuntime en el config, la defines en el cliente o en el servidor ?

Comment: tienes que hacerlo a ambos extremos, es decir tanto en el servicio como en el cliente.

Comment: Si ta me resulto, me faltaba hacerlo en ambos lados y tuve que tambien recompital. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Definiste tambien el "binding" desde tu aplicación cliente?:

**Servidor:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding maxBufferSize="30000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="30000000" />

        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Cliente**:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Name = "MyBind";
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 30000000;
```

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta. Hice los cambios y no hay diferencia, tengo el mismo archivo de descarga

Answer (score 0):

En adición a lo que sugiere *@LeandroTuttini* y *@Elenasys*

intenta agregar esto a tu `web.config` o `app.config`

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Puedes cambiar la cifra por `2147483647` que es el valor máximo que puede tomar un `Int32`